# How to get around anti-adblock html page while scraping using python requests library?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, https

I'm trying to automate a clerical report that I have been assigned and a part of that involves getting the zip code from a street address. I have tried a bunch of stuff like the geopy library and I even tried to use the chatgpt API to get the zip code. These methods gave me mostly accurate results but weren't perfect so I couldn't really use them. Now I'm trying to scrape information off of a reliable website, https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org, to get the zip code using the requests library.

As a test, I made this code to see what I would get:

```
import requests 



test_URL = "https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org"

def get_data(link):

    
    hdr = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

    req = requests.get(link, headers=hdr)
    content = req.text

    
    return content


data = get_data(test_URL)
```

But when I looked at the HTML page that I received, all it said was to delete ad blocker. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be to add Google Web-cache URL just before your URL, for example:

```py
import requests

test_URL = "https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org"
cache_URL = "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:"


def get_data(link):
    hdr = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    }
    req = requests.get(cache_URL + link, headers=hdr)
    content = req.text
    return content


data = get_data(test_URL)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><base href="https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/"><style>body{margin-left:0;margin-right:0;margin-top:0}#bN015htcoyT__google-cache-hdr{background:#f8f9fa;font:13px arial,sans-serif;text-align:left;color:#202124;border:0;margin:0;border-bottom:1px solid #dadce0;line-height:16px;padding:16px 28px 24px 28px}#bN015htcoyT__google-cache-hdr *{display:inline;font:inherit;text-align:inherit;color:inherit;line-height:inherit;background:none;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;letter-spacing:0}#bN015htcoyT__google-cache-hdr a{text-decoration:none;color:#1558d6;}#bN015htcoyT__google-cache-hdr a:hover{text-decoration:underline}#bN015htcoyT__google-cache-hdr a:visited{color:#681da8}#bN015htcoyT__google-cache-hdr div{display:block;margin-top:4px}#bN015htcoyT__google-cache-hdr b{font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;direction:ltr}</style><div id="bN015htcoyT__google-cache-hdr"><div><span>Toto je vyrovnávacia pamäť Google pre <a href="https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/">https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/</a>.</span>&nbsp;<span>Je to snímka stránky, ako sa zobrazila dňa 7. feb. 2023 13:26:55 GMT.</span>&nbsp;<span><a href="https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/">Aktuálna stránka</a> sa odvtedy mohla zmeniť.</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=sk&amp;p=cached&amp;answer=1687222"><span>Ďalšie informácie</span>.</a></div><div><span style="display:inline-block;margin-top:8px;margin-right:104px;white-space:nowrap"><span style="margin-right:28px"><span style="font-weight:bold">Úplná verzia</span></span><span style="margin-right:28px"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org&amp;prmd=ivn&amp;strip=1&amp;vwsrc=0"><span>Len textová verzia</span></a></span><span style="margin-right:28px"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org&amp;prmd=ivn&amp;strip=0&amp;vwsrc=1"><span>Zobraziť zdroj</span></a></span></span></div><span style="display:inline-block;margin-top:8px;color:#70757a"><span>Tip: Ak chcete rýchlo nájsť hľadaný výraz na tejto stránke, stlačte klávesy <b>Ctrl+F</b> alebo <b>⌘-F</b> (Mac) a použite panel vyhľadávania.</span></span></div><div style="position:relative;"><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Free ZIP code map, zip code lookup, and zip code list</title>
    <meta name="description" content="United States Zip Codes provides a free zip code map and list of zip codes by state. Find zip codes by address, zip codes by city, or zip codes by state.">

...
```